# Could you demo a very simple C++ example about Symbolic variable and Jacobian by converting Pydrake code to C++ version?

Tags: drake

I am trying to convert the following pydrake code to C++ version. Unfortunately,I get lost in the very rigorous C++ API documentation. Could you help to convert the following code into C++ version for a tutorial? Thank you so much!

```
import pydrake.math as drake_math
import pydrake.symbolic as sym

def cost_stage(x):
    m = sym if x.dtype == object else np # Check type for autodiff
    cost = m.sqrt(x[0]**2 + x[1]**2 ) 
    return cost

x_sym = np.array([sym.Variable("x_{}".format(i)) for i in range(n_x)])
x = x_sym
l = cost_stage(x)
self.l_x = sym.Jacobian([l], x).ravel()
```

Comment: Do you want to use this cost in drake's MathematicalProgram, or you just want the symbolic expression on the cost Jacobian?

Comment: I guess the answer is the latter. The above code is part of iLQR exercise which does a lot of derivatives for Q-function expansion(We get the quadaratic cost function finally).

Comment: Then you just need the template DoEvalGeneric function as I wrote in the comment.

Comment: I just updated my answer below, that uses a templated function `cost_stage`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you used the name "cost", I suppose you want to use this as a cost in drake's MathematicalProgram, so I created `MyCost` class which can be used in Drake's MathematicalProgram. If you don't want to use MathematicalProgram later, you could just use the templated function `DoEvalGeneric` only without the class `MyCost`.

Here is the C++ pseudo-code (I didn't compile or run the code, so it is highly likely there are bugs in the code, but you get the idea)

```cc
#include "drake/solvers/cost.h"
#include "drake/common/symbolic.h"

class MyCost : public drake::solvers::Cost {
 public:
  MyCost() {}
 
 protected:
  void DoEval(const Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::VectorXd>& x, Eigen::VectorXd* y) const override {
    DoEvalGeneric<double>(x, y);
  }

  void DoEval(const Eigen::Ref<const drake::AutoDiffVecXd>& x, drake::AutoDiffVecXd* y) const override {
    DoEvalGeneric<drake::AutoDiffXd>(x, y)
  }
  
  void DoEval(const Eigen::Ref<const drake::VectorX<drake::symbolic::Variable>>& x, drake::VectorX<drake::symbolic::Expression>* y) const override {
    DoEvalGeneric<drake::symbolic::Expression>(x.cast<drake::symbolic::Expression>(), y);
  }

 private:
  template <typename T>
  void DoEvalGeneric(const Eigen::Ref<const drake::VectorX<T>>& x, drake::VectorX<T>* y) const {
    y->resize(1);
    using std::sqrt
    (*y)(0) = sqrt(x[0] * x[0] + x[1] * x[1]);
  }
};

void main() {
  const drake::symbolic::Variable x0{"x0"};
  const drake::symbolic::Variable x1{"x1"};
  drake::Vector2<drake::symbolic::Variable> x(x0, x1);
  MyCost cost{};
  drake::VectorX<drake::symbolic::Expression> y;
  cost.Eval(x, &y);
  std::cout << y(0).Jacobian(x) << "\n";
}
```

Here I created a templated function `DoEvalGeneirc` to handle the three different scalar types double, AutoDiffXd and symbolic expression. You could see similar patterns in the drake codebase https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/6ee5e9325821277a62bd5cd5456ccf02ca25dab7/solvers/cost.cc#L14-L33

If you don't need to use `cost` in drake MathematicalProgram, then you can create your `cost` function in C++ as

```cc
#include "drake/common/symbolic.h"

#include <Eigen/Core>


template <typename Derived>
typename Derived::Scalar cost_stage(const Derived& x) {
  using std::sqrt;
  return sqrt(x[0] * x[0] + x[1] * x[1]);
}

int main() {
  const drake::symbolic::Variable x0{"x0"};
  const drake::symbolic::Variable x1{"x1"};
  drake::Vector2<drake::symbolic::Variable> x(x0, x1);
  const drake::symbolic::Expression l = cost_stage(x.cast<drake::symbolic::Expression>());
  std::cout << l.Jacobian(x) << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Then you can call `Jacobian` on the return argument of `cost_stage`.

Comment: Thank you for providing this code. It is a great help to me.

Comment: After a lot of effort, I still get two errors, I appreciate it if you can help to correct them.

Comment: error 1: missing 'typename' prior to dependent type name 'Derived::Scalar'
Derived::Scalar cost_stage(const Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived>>& x) {

Comment: error 2: no matching function for call to 'cost_stage'
  const drake::symbolic::Expression l = cost_stage(x.cast<drake::symbolic::Expression>());

Comment: I updated that code above, it compiles and runs on my machine.

Comment: It works on my computer now.  Thanks!   By the way, I search "cast" in the API documentation, it supports several methods in math and multibody class, but not includes vector or symbolic class. It is quite interesting.